# How can I make all my bash scripts use aliases in .bashrc?

Tags: bash

I know adding

```
source ~/.bashrc
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

to a bash script allows to use aliases.

Is there a way to achieve this without editing existing scripts?

Something like adding lines to bashrc file, setting env variables, or else.

There are so many existing bash scripts, and I also want this alias applied to newly created bash scripts automatically.

Any comment, link appreciated.

Comment: You can try using `BASH_ENV` for this, but it seems like an *extremely* bad idea. You don't know what things you commonly run are actually using bash scripts under the hood.

Comment: @muru Thanks for your comment. Could you please elaborate more why it's a bad idea? I found out that adding `export BASH_ENV=.bashrc` works well.

Comment: How can you be certain that some script you might use is not assuming something different from what your bashrc does (or will do, as you update it)?

Comment: Okay I get what you mean. Thanks :)